# Freeswitch Hangup issue

Tags: python, freeswitch, ivr, dialplan

I run a Python script that plays iVR and bridges to the available extension (agent) in my freeswitch. It functions correctly, but when the customer or agent hangs up, the call is still in an active position when I check show calls. My best assumption is that the remaining dialplan processes are not handled after the ivr script has been executed. If you have any ideas, please...

What I was hoping for was that the call would end when the customer or agent disconnected, thus I tried invoking the zombie flag and continue_on_fail="true" in dialplan type of things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: session.execute("bridge", f"{{zombie_exec=true,verto_h_test={held_uuid},hangup_after_bridge=true}}user/{new_extension}")
                                #session.execute("hangup", "")
this is how i bridge the call